# Как работать с матрицами, как их обрабатывать?

Tags: python, матрицы

Здраствуйте. Есть задание на одном из тренировочных сайтов. Вот как оно звучит - 
"Дана квадратная матрица размера N x N. Необходимо проверить есть ли здесь последовательность 4 или более 
одинаковых цифр. Последовательность должна неразрывно располагаться горизонтально, вертикально или по диагоналям 
(основным и дополнительным).

Входные данные: Матрица, как список (list) списков с целыми числами.

Выходные данные: Есть ли здесь последовательность, как булево значение (bool).

Примеры:

```
checkio([
    [1, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 4, 1],
    [1, 3, 1, 6],
    [1, 7, 2, 5]
    ]) == True
```

Раньше решал матрицу 3 на 3. там занёс правильные решения в список и проверял в цикле. Как решать подобные задачи с большими матрицами? Подскажите пожалуйста. Можете ответ написать, я его запишу в заметки и буду анализировать(читай-учится). Можете советов накидать.

Нашёл здесь такой же вопрос, где один из ответов,от ув.Kromster, мне обьяснил фронт работы, вот он:

> 1- научитесь проверять есть ли 4+ одинаковых подряд элемента в простом списке (если не получается, задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос об этом (и только об этом)) 2- сгенерируйте все ряды, столбцы, диагонали и примените функцию проверки для списка к каждому.

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Все правильно Kromaster сказал. Проще всего взять и пройтись сначала по всем столбцам, затем строкам, затем диагоналям. Можно выгрузить в отдельные листы, но это будет занимать много памяти, так что лучше сразу по матрице. А как найти побочную и основную диагонали в инете полно решений